# Usage of ORDER BY after WHERE

Tags: mysql

I want to order my result using ORDER BY after the WHERE clause.

I tried something like this:

```
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id']. "order by bottom desc";
```

It gives me `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()`.

Without ORDER BY my query is working fine:

```
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id'];
```

Comment: Add a space so your dynamically generated sql makes sense after substitution: `$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id']." order by bottom desc";`

Comment: Wowu.....Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id']. " order by bottom desc";
```

add a space after double quote and order

" order

Answer (score 0):

Place a space before `ORDER BY` clause.

```
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid = {$rowcd['id']} order by bottom desc";
```

Comment: Someone downvoted. Is there a valid reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have problems sometimes with the spaces. I think there must be space before order keyword.

```
$queryl = "select * from logs where pid=".$rowcd['id']. " order by bottom desc";
```